# How to convert a dataframe into a different format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to build a model to predict on some sales data but the data I have is currently formatted like this:

| ITEM | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-03-01 .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM 1 | 3 | 0 | 80 |
| ITEM 2 | 25 | 60 | 70 |

Is there a way to convert the data into something like this where it is much cleaner and easier to manipulate? The columns plot the graphs and also build a model to predict the sales.

| ITEM | 2022-01-01 | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM 1 | 2022-01-01 | 3 |
| ITEM 1 | 2022-02-01 | 60 |
| ITEM 1 | 2022-03-01 | 0 |

If there is a better way to predict the sales for model building or a better model that can use the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want to achieve by using `df.melt`. It essentially **melts** the dataframe from wide to long format.

```
output_df = df.melt(id_vars='ITEM', var_name='Date', value_name='Sales')
```

And to further achieve the end result you wish for, the data needs to be sorted.
This can be achieved like this:

```
output_df.sort_values(by=['ITEM', 'Date'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is beyond the scope of this site to recommend approaches to solving the broad modelling problem.  With respect to your desire to change the orientation of the initial dataframe, here are a couple of steps which accomplish that task.

Given you initial dataframe entitled df, you can use the following:

```
df.set_index('ITEM', drop=True, inplace=True)
df.transpose()
```

Which produces:

```
ITEM    ITEM 1  ITEM 2
2022-01-01  3   25
2022-02-01  0   60
2022-03-01  80  70
```